# Однозначный поиск слова в строке

Tags: c++, строки

Нужно однозначно проверять, есть ли в строке конкретное слово, например, если строка содержит `COMPUTER`, будет выведено *true*. И при содержании строкой слова `SERVER_COMPUTER` также будет выведено *true*. Как добится однозначности?

```
if (item.find("COMPUTER") != std::string::npos)
{
    std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проще некуда (можно проверить на [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
int main ()
{
    std::string str = "SERVER_COMPUTER";
    std::regex rx("\\bCOMPUTER\\b");
    std::cout << std::regex_search(str, rx) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Если слово нашлось, смотрите на символы, которые стоят по соседству. Если они вам нравятся (например, это пробелы и знаки препинания), можно считать, что слово нашлось однозначно.

Answer (score 3):

Проверить, что
найденная позиция - 0, либо символ перед найденной позицией - разделитель
И
найденная позиция плюс длина шаблона больше или равна длине текста, либо символ сразу после шаблона - разделитель.